# grep a log file starting from specific time to the end of file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, scripting

I have a log file which has a date and time at the start of every line.

I need to search the log file starting from a specific time to the end of the file.

For example:

```
Starting point: July 29 2018 21:00:00
End point     : end of file
```

My concern is even if the pattern of `July 29 2018 21:00:00` does not exist, I still get the lines between for example `July 29 2018 21:05:11` since this is still beyond `July 29 2018 21:00:00`.

Is `awk` or `sed` work for this?

Comment: can you share the sample file..

Comment: Is this something ausearch can perform?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use perl for this, to parse the timestamp on each line:

```
$ cat file
June 5 2018 00:00:00 do not print
July 29 2018 20:59:59 do not print
July 29 2018 21:00:00 print me
July 29 2018 21:00:01 print me

$ perl -MTime::Piece -sane '
    BEGIN {
        $start = Time::Piece->strptime($startdate, "%B %e %Y %T");
    }
    # the string "@F[0..3]" is the first 4 words on the line
    $time = Time::Piece->strptime("@F[0..3]", "%B %e %Y %T");
    print if $time >= $start;
' -- -startdate="July 29 2018 21:00:00" file
```

```
July 29 2018 21:00:00 print me
July 29 2018 21:00:01 print me
```

This version is somewhat more efficient, as it stops parsing the timestamp once the start date has been seen (assumes the file is in increasing cronological order):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -sane '
    BEGIN {
        $start = Time::Piece->strptime($startdate, "%B %e %Y %T");
    }
    unless ($go) {
        $time = Time::Piece->strptime("@F[0..3]", "%B %e %Y %T");
        $go = $time >= $start;
    }
    print if $go;
' -- -startdate="July 29 2018 21:00:00" file
```

Comment: +1 compared to my solution this is just superfast. `awk` with a system call for `date` was even slower.

Comment: GNU awk (gawk) has [builtin time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions), but parsing times is still quite manual.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grepfromdate() {
    readarray f < $1
    fromdate=$(date +%s -d "$2")
    for (( lineno=${#f[@]}-1 ; lineno>=0; lineno-- )) ; do
        line=${f[$lineno]}
        time_from_line=$(echo "$line" | grep -o "^[A-Z][a-z]* [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]")
        [[ $(date +%s -d "$time_from_line") -gt $fromdate ]] && echo "$line" || break
    done | tac
}
```

> Usage:
>   `grepfromdate "filename" "July 29 2018 21:00:00"`

You can pass any date format that `date` can read to it, e.g. `2018-07-01`.
If the format of the date changes, you can change the `grep` pattern according to that.

Comment: this is slow as it needs to open the file for each line

Comment: it also needs to invoke sed, grep and date (twice) for each line.

Comment: I changed the script and now read the file into an array to remove invocation of sed, changed date to be invoked only once. But still one date and one grep for each line.  Still that doubled the performance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the first line matching a defined String (i.e. `July 29 2018 21:` for everything after 9 pm).
If you have this line number, you can `tail` the file starting with the found line number.

```
   $ man tail
   -n, --lines=[+]NUM
          output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```

my example:

```
$ log=/var/log/syslog

# get line number
$ first_line=$(grep -no "Aug 14 08:" $log | tail -n1 | cut -d: -f1)

# count the lines from $first_line to EOF
$ tail -n +$first_line $log | wc -l
24071

# output the content starting with $first_line
$ tail -n +$first_line $log

# line count of the whole file:
$ wc -l $log
70896 /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can do

```
sed -n '/July 29 2018 21:/,/$!d/p' file
```

That will get you all lines between July 29 2018 21:** and the last line of file